# How do I exclude consecutive characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

My pattern is

```
^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-_.]*[a-z0-9\-_]$
```

I want to exclude one or more consecutive periods.

1.1.1.1 -----> GOOD 
1..1.1.1 ------> BAD

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the Regex flavor you are using? Different tools supports different functionalities for Regex.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I use javascript regex.

Comment: you can refactor: `^[a-z0-9](?:[.]?[a-z0-9\-_]+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/QUAGVv/1

Answer (score 0):

If just want to avoid any occurrence of dots being adjacent to each other, try the [word boundary](https://javascript.info/regexp-boundary) meta escape `\b`.

```
/\b[.]\b/g
```

[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/SmsyIE/1)